# Checkstyle plugin for eclipse

Tags: checkstyle

Eclipse has checkstyle plugin which points out the coding practices which are not good. Is there some tool or someway in which some of those issues can be automatically fixed?
 For example, let's say cleanup unused imports. If the tool can automatically visit the whole project and remove the unused imports?

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse has since the version 3.3  a cleanup wizard that could help doing part of the job. But in my opinion, the question is asked in the wrong way:

- Checkstyle does check a lot of different things, and some of them could be automatically corrected. So by using the automatic format of Eclipse, and tweaking the format that it complies to Checkstyle, these warnings will go away automatically.
- Some of the warnings indicate that something is missing which is not known. Most prominent are here comments everywhere, but there could be other warnings as well. Eclipse may here help partially, but  it is not a good idea to generate JavaDoc by eclipse with its standard templates, because then the indication that something is wrong is gone, but the cause exists further.
- Some of the warnings indicate something for which multiple solutions could exist. So it is not possible for Eclipse to automatically change the code. There sometimes a quick fix exists that may be appropriate, but each has to be selected by the user.

So you should do the following:

1. Have a look at the Cleanup Wizard in Eclipse `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Clean Up`, create there a new profile from an existing one, and tweak it to the rules you want to use in Checkstyle.
2. If you have selected `Code Organizing > Format Source Code` in your profile, tweak the code formatter for Java as well. Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`, create here as well a new profile as well, and tweak it according to your checkstyle rules. The rule of thumb should be that after writing any code and formatting it with the formatter, no checkstyle warning should exist that could be corrected by only inserting or removing spaces, blanks, newlines, and parantheses.
3. Ensure that this configuration is used by everyone in your project, and of course everyone should use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I found a link at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-clean/ which answers this question.